Total variation distance of discrete gaussian and discrete uniform($-\lceil \sigma\rceil+1, \lceil \sigma\rceil$)
I want to find the statistical distance (Total variation distance) between a discrete gaussian centered in $0$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, and a discrete uniform with set $(-\lceil \sigma\rceil, \lceil \sigma\rceil]$. I tried to find it but I don't know very well how the gaussian behaves in discrete form.
Here are the probability density functions:
$$
\rho(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp({-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}})
$$
$$
\lambda(x) = \frac{1}{2\lceil\sigma\rceil-1}
$$
Definition of statistical distance in a measure space ($\Omega, \mathcal{F}$):
$$
\Delta(\rho, \lambda) = \sup_{A\in\mathcal{F}}| \rho(A) - \lambda(A) | 
$$
In this case, since it is discrete, I believe we can use:
$$
\Delta(\rho, \lambda) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{x} |P(x) - Q(x)|
$$
If I am not mistaken.

Please provide the densities. It is not possible to help you if there is important context missing as to what objects you are actually working with.

I added the density functions, I thought they were known by most people that post here, my apologies.

What do you mean by "discrete" here?

Everything is in $\mathbb{Z}$, you can truncate the real gaussian if that is relevant, there is no really reason on asking this because the PDFs are given now.

If $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, what does it mean to speak of a PDF for such a discrete variable? Don't you run into trouble because $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\rho(n) \neq 1$ for the Gaussian you've given?

I didn't understand your question very well, but $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \rho(n) = 1$, as I said, you can round/truncate the gaussian and the definition of discrete gaussian distribution $D$ can be given as $D(x) = \rho(x)/\rho(\mathbb{Z})$ where $\rho(x)$ is the corresponding continuous normal distribution over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\rho(\mathbb{Z}) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \rho(n)$.
